# Do I need to have an A record to send/receive mail?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, hosting, a-record, send

This is basic level question, I'm not running my own servers.
I've bought a domain name, but I wonder, do I also have to buy hosting with an A record, or I can just configure DNS mail records in the domain's dashboard?

Answer (score 3):

You need an `MX` record to receive email (and in its absence, a fallback exists to direct `A`/`AAAA` records).

This can point to any host handling email for you, it does not need to be on your servers.

So you first need to select an email provider and then ask it what DNS records you need to put for things to work.

PS: don't be stuck in legacy old Internet using IPv4, current one uses IPv6 aka `AAAA` records in the DNS.